# Git tab completion stopped working on remote branches

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I've updated git to its latest version (2.29.0) and I'm using ZSH 5.8.

I used to switch between branches with `git checkout remote_br<tab>` to quickly switch between branches, even if the branch is only a remote one atm. I've seen git has made a lot of changes regarding switch/checkout [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551755/5692012), the thing is my autocompletion on remote branches doesn't work anymore (with checkout or switch).

I've tried to add the latest version of `contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh` to my zsh, but I still have my issue. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: As you've seen, there has been a mini-flurry of activity on the completion scripts, to account for the `switch` command and so on. I recall there was a change or two to make DWIM completion optional as well. It sounds like it's turned off in yours. I don't actually use this feature and I don't remember what the enable/disable settings are.

Comment: Note that when you've run `git fetch` and picked up a new remote-tracking name such as `origin/xyz-feature`, you don't actually have a (local) branch name `xyz-feature` at all. The switch or checkout command will *create* your `xyz-feature` from `origin/xyz-feature` on demand, and Git refers to this as "checkout DWIM" (Do What I Mean).

Comment: The reason for making this optional is that some repositories have hundreds of similarly-named branches, so that if you *do* use completion, and have one local branch named `sanity` for instance, but your upstream has 78 branches whose names all start with `s`, you can't just type `s<tab>`. Turning off DWIM-style completion, you *can* just type `s<tab>`. But in your case, you want it turned *on*. That might be a useful hint in looking through the completion scripts, anyway.

Comment: I've read trough all recent change logs, I don't see anything. When looking at the commits I think it may be related to something like: https://github.com/git/git/commit/68d97c7fdd5bbfd87b2e0b14ddfcd2b1825b2059 but I don't see the issue. I've checked `__git_checkout_default_dwim_mode` which returns `--dwim` as expected.

Comment: Any solution for the issue? I did a downgrade to 2.27.0, but that's not satisfying.

Comment: Nope, still stuck, had to downgrade too.

Comment: as of git version 2.30.0 (released 2020-12-27), this seems to have been fixed. I have updated and it is working properly for me in zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following patch:

```
--- a/git-completion.zsh
+++ b/git-completion.zsh
@@ -97,6 +97,11 @@ __gitcomp_direct ()
        compadd -Q -S '' -- ${(f)1} && _ret=0
 }
 
+__gitcomp_direct_append ()
+{
+       __gitcomp_direct "$@"
+}
+
 __gitcomp_nl ()
 {
        emulate -L zsh
```

In general it's better to report bugs to the [git mailing list](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity), however, I'm the maintainer of the zsh code, which is more up to date in my fork: [git-completion](https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/).

Comment: It works on local branches but not on remote ones. As long as the branch has not been fetched, the auto-completion doesn't work. (Tested with your current master: https://github.com/felipec/git-completion/blob/282bb9bc13b926f5e6fbbc0966570220a63f37ad/git-completion.bash)

Comment: @FelipeC Should I direct my [PR](https://github.com/git/git/pull/902) to you?

Comment: BTW your suggestion is very similar to what [I did](https://github.com/git/git/pull/902/files#diff-ac06d8a41d816b7182a4755e4258784c81b9b151bb5f6eabb32bc6465b419486R834)

Comment: @RobinFrcd It should work on both. Exactly as it does in Bash. Do you have a test case where it doesn't?

Comment: Forgot to edit my comment, everything works as expected now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this for the last few hours and have identified the regression.

The regression occurs in [6880779](https://github.com/git/git/commit/688077910bdfbd502cb59c9c48a2af2c97d8b67b).

To temporarily resolve this: replace your `git-completion.bash` file (mine's located at `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash`) with [https://github.com/git/git/blob/688077910bdfbd502cb59c9c48a2af2c97d8b67b~1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/688077910bdfbd502cb59c9c48a2af2c97d8b67b%7E1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

To really resolve this, upvote my git [PR](https://github.com/git/git/pull/902) and help get it merged! (https://github.com/git/git/pull/902)

Comment: Same as @FelipeC, it works on local branches but not on remote ones. As long as the branch has not been fetched, the auto-completion doesn't work for me :/

Comment: The version I posted here works for remote branches

Comment: Or better yet: Just use Zsh's built-in Git completion. It's way better than the one that ships with Git.

Comment: This patch already has been sent to the ML and it's already queued. No need to send a PR.

https://lore.kernel.org/git/20201028020712.442623-14-felipe.contreras@gmail.com/